# What is a smooth family of divisors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, schemes

Suppose that $S$ is a smooth complex projective surface ($\mathbb C$-scheme, reduced, irreducible...).

> What do algebraic geometers usually mean with the term a *smooth family of divisors in $S$*?

In general with the notation *family $\mathcal F$ over an "object" $X$*, I intend that there exists a morphism $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ (where $Y$ "is an object of the same type of $X$") such that every fiber $Y_x:=f^{-1}(x)$ is an element of the family $\mathcal F$.

So in my case do I have to find a variety $Y$ and a morphism $f:Y\longrightarrow S$ such that every fiber $Y_s$ is a divisor of $S$? Moreover such a morphism $f$ is supposed to be smooth...

Comment: Can you give an example of where you read this? It's not a phrase that strikes me as very common, so context is important.

Comment: It is a terminology used by Zariski (or Mumford), for example in the book "Algebraic Surfaces".

Comment: You have your arrow backwards: it should be $f:S\to Y$